# Apparmor: Allow Inkscape to execute extensions in $HOME/config/inkscape/extensions/

Tags: 20.04, snap, apparmor, inkscape

I want to extend Inkscape (installed with snap) by putting the SVGO-Optimizer [SVGO](https://github.com/svg/svgo) in Inkscape's local extension directory.

According to the Inkscape preferences dialog (Edit/Preferences/System), the directory to use is (and to put extensions in)

`$HOME/.config/inkscape/extensions/`

There I want to install `inkscape-svgo.inx`. I followed [the inkscape-svgo instructions](https://github.com/konsumer/inkscape-svgo).

however, Apparmor does not let me execute the extension from within the Inkscape GUI. I cannot execute the "Save As SVGO-Optimized SVG " dialog.

An uninformative "Saving as [any filename] failed" dialog appears.

**I suspect it is an Apparmor issue.

How can I defined or extend the Apparmor rule to allow Inkscape to execute the SVGO extension?**

`journalctl` gives me this output:

```
AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.inkscape.inkscape" name="/proc/148064/mountinfo" pid=148064 comm="inkscape" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="snap.inkscape.inkscape" name="$HOME/.config/inkscape/extensions/inkscape-svgo" pid=149456 comm="inkscape" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Script::execute(): failed to execute program '$HOME/.config/inkscape/extensions/inkscape-svgo'. 
Reason: Failed to execute child process “$HOME/.config/inkscape/extensions/inkscape-svgo” (Permission denied)
```

My Inkscape version:

```
snap list inkscape
Name      Version                    Rev   Tracking       Publisher  Notes
inkscape  1.1-ce6663b3b7-2021-05-25  9090  latest/stable  inkscape✓  -
```

These are the inkscape apparmor profile files, in directory `/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/`:

```
38032  /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.inkscape.hook.configure
75557  /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.inkscape.inkscape
70951  /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.inkscape.viewer
```

First number is file size in bytes.
As you can see they are very long, complicated, and depend on each other.

Comment: I see overcomplication in proposed solution. Using deb-package [from PPA](https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable?field.series_filter=focal) will be easier.

Comment: ? I did not propose a solution, I've asked a question. Specifically about the Inkscape version distributed as a Snap.

Answer (score 1):

AppArmor rules are defined in profiles which are stored in `/etc/apparmor.d/`
You need to update the AppArmor profile with rules to permit filesystem access to the paths you are interested in for Inkscape.

[This tutorial from Ubuntu will help to guide you.](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/beginning-apparmor-profile-development#1-overview)

[More details can be found in the AppArmor documentation, here.](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-apparmor)

Comment: Or, I guess, you could not use snap packages

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to read documentation. The thing is, the existing aparmor profile defined in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real` is really long and complex. Even disabling apparmor with `systemctl disable apparmor` does not help. Do I need to log out / reboot? That is what I need an answer for.

Comment: Disabling AppArmor will not help; it will prevent all profiles from granting permissions. Container privileges fail closed by default. Instead, you must edit the profile in accordance with the documentation.